# mobile redirection domain level, keep page url

Tags: android, mobile, jquery-mobile, url-rewriting

I've found mobile detection and redirection scripts but on a "whole" site level, for instance, if you reach an inner page (ex: www.site.com/this_page.php) with a mobile/smartphone/tablet, you are redirected to the proxy subdomain site, lets say m.site.com.

This is not suitable for what I need, I'm looking for something thats good on browser/device detection, but then redirect you to the exact same page but on the subdomain, using the above example, it should be:  m.site.com/this_page.php,

Is there such a script?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly, you should be able to use a device detection script (php or otherwise) at any point in your website. For example, using your example with the [51Degrees.mobi](http://51degrees.mobi?CATReferrer=1765) framework:

```
<?php
include('51Degrees/51Degrees.mobi.php');

$IsMobile = $_51d["IsMobile"] == "True";
    if ($IsMobile)
        redirect(m.site.com);
    else
        redirect(www.site.com);
?>
```

This could be embedded within the HTML of your index, but could also be placed in /this_page.php as well:

```
<?php
include('51Degrees/51Degrees.mobi.php');

$IsMobile = $_51d["IsMobile"] == "True";
    if ($IsMobile)
        redirect(m.site.com/this_page.php);
    else
        redirect(www.site.com/this_page.php);
?>
```

It's up to you where you place the code.